# The degrees of ordinary characters of $PSp(2n,q)$ and $P\Omega O(2n+1,q)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, characters

The finite simple groups $PSp(2n,q)$ and $P\Omega O(2n+1,q)$ have a same order, where $n\geqslant3$ and $q$ is odd.

> What are the degrees of the ordinary characters of these two groups?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you check if GAP knows this? For several classes of finite groups of Lie type there are generic character tables available thanks to the work of Frank Lübeck and some other people. (And Lübeck's work would also be a good place to start looking for answers if it isn't already implemented in GAP)

Comment: This is in the end section of Carter's *Finite groups of Lie type*. It is too long and involved to right down as an answer here, but if you want an e-copy of the book email me.